ArcGIS Online; Calculation using raster DEM value
I am pretty new to ArcGIS online and am trying to figure something out.
I have a map I am creating with the only layer being a raster DEM. When a user selects the location it reports the DEM value. This I have running no problem.
The last thing I would like to have is the ability within the popup for the user to also have a field they could enter a height, and it would return a value that has been adjusted using the height pulled from the DEM. This would clear as soon as they select somewhere else, so not saving at all.
So the DEM may have a value of 10, I want a box they could enter the value  4, and it would return the number 14. Is this possible?
